# How to add one value to all values in a column with the same id

Tags: r, dataframe

I am quite new to R and never worked with any bigger data. For the examples i reduced the two dataframes:

- `df1`

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 1 | 2 |
| 11 | 2 | 5 |
| 22 | 2 | 2 |
| 22 | 4 | 6 |
| ... | ... | ... |

- `df2`

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 5 | 3 |
| 22 | 6 | 5 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I am looking for a way to add the values of df2 to each value in df1 with the same id.

So the result should be something like this:

| id | val1 | val2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 6 | 5 |
| 11 | 7 | 8 |
| 22 | 8 | 7 |
| 22 | 10 | 11 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Because the original data is over 3000 observations of 47 variables with 8 different id I am looking for a solution where the values are not added one by one.

```
#reproducible data
df1 <- read.table(text = "id val1 val2
  11 1   2   
  11 2   5   
  22 2   2   
  22 4   6", header = TRUE)
df2 <- read.table(text = "id val1 val2
  11 5   3   
  22 6   5", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Merge two datasets on "id", then do the adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to merge both datasets by the `id` variable, then additioning corresponding columns to create the new `val1` and `val2` variables, as suggested in the comments by @zx8754. Using `dplyr` you can obtain the output with :

```
library(dplyr)
merge(df1,df2,by="id") %>% 
  mutate(val1=val1.x+val1.y,val2=val2.x+val2.y,)%>%
  select(id,val1,val2)
```

Comment: You have loaded the `dplyr` package. Why not using `left_join()` rather than `merge`?

Comment: There are multiple possibilities yes, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could use `powerjoin` to handle conflicted columns when joining.

```r
library(powerjoin)

power_left_join(df1, df2, by = "id", conflict = `+`)

#   id val1 val2
# 1 11    6    5
# 2 11    7    8
# 3 22    8    7
# 4 22   10   11
```

Answer (score 2):

Merge the datasets then add columns:

```
# merge
res <- merge(df1, df2, by = "id")
# then add
cbind(res[ 1 ], res[, 2:3] + res[, 4:5])
#   id val1.x val2.x
# 1 11      6      5
# 2 11      7      8
# 3 22      8      7
# 4 22     10     11
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach - row bind then index by the table when summing

```
library(tidyverse)   
imap(list(df1,df2), ~
        mutate(.x, table = .y)) %>%
        bind_rows() %>%
        group_by(id) %>%
        summarise(across(matches("val"), ~ .[table == 1] + .[table == 2]),.groups = "drop")
```